# Autoarrange subviews in a zoomed UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to zoom in and out an `UIView`, and rearrange it content to look similar for both states: zoomed and normal. 
This picture shows the default state (the view that I'm going to zoom has orange color and has 5 UIImageViews) :

[image]

When I press "Zoom in" button I change orange view frame:

```
_page.frame = self.view.bounds;
```

And I'm getting the following result:

[image]

But the goal that I want to achieve is something similar to this (same result if I would scale the view):

[image]

It means that I must change frames for each subview, but it could be complicated when view would have many objects on it.
What I'm asking for are some hints or methods how can I get desired result without accessing subviews.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to setting the frame (which just changes the size of the view) you want to change the transform (scale the view)  Try something like:

```
_page.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(2.0, 2.0)
```

You'll probably want to calculate the scale factor based on the old view size and the new size.

Comment: Thanks! This seems to be the simplest and most convenient way.

Comment: I'll also say that Anindya's answer is better if you assume:  1)  you're already using auto layout; 2) you don't have text attached to the + (I don't think you can get it to conveniently resize with auto layout, although setting it to auto shrink might work; and, 3) the items in the view are relatively static (maintaining the constraints for dynamically created views might be tedious)

Answer (score 2):

There are be hacks to do this, but the proper way would be to use auto layout. You don't have to access any subviews and will be able to do it in the storyboard/IB.
If you use auto layout, you can actually create constraints which will pin the following attributes of the subviews:

- Pin the top subview's top space and leading space to the container
- Pin the all but the last subviews' vertical distance to its nearest neighbour and leading space to container
- Pin the last subview's top vertical space to its nearest neighbour and bottom space to container and leading space to container
- Set constraints for height and width but set the priority to low